# Is a new request better than pass parameters by listview in android?

Tags: android, json, listview, httprequest

I'm doing a listview in Android that takes the date from a json with some information, I want to know the fastest way to create a new activity with all the data of one item.

What is more efficiently pass and id of the item in the intent and make a new request in the new activity or pass all the data of the new activity in the intent?

I guess that make two requests is worse than make one and pass the data in the intent, but maybe this information is too big to pass in the intent.putextra();

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same information in the Listview that you'll have in the activity, then passing that info should be faster than making another request.

Nevertheless, if you only show a small piece of info in your ListView (which will also make it smoother) and then you show the full item when an element is clicked, then the first aproach is better.

**Example:**

I have a list with my contacts names and when i select one, i open a new activity requesting and showing all data of that contact.

This will be faster than have all unused info in my ListView.